# Get Folder from which application was called

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to be called from a folder's context menu that should create a folder in that folder. How do I get the path of that folder, rather than the directory the executable resides in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271326/get-directory-where-executed-code-is-located?

Comment: The title of that question is exactly what I'm not looking for. I don't want to find out where the application is located, but where the application was called from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to get the path of current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is in the args. My problem was that calling the application from a shortcut left the current directory at the executable path. Instead I'll just make the application available on path, and then the correct path will be passed in.