# Application cannot find my .ico file

Tags: c#

Application cannot find my ico file.
Where should I add picture ? 
I get an **unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("mmm.ico");
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try "new Icon("~\mmm.ico");" ?

Comment: Define "cannot find". What happens?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'

Comment: Did you set the properties of that file to "copy if newer" or "copy always"? that way it'll copy the file to the exe directory automatically

Comment: Or add it as a Resource to embed it in the exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you try to load the icon from you application folder, but it is in your **Project** folder (move the Icon-File to the Bin/Debug or Bin/Release folder).

If you want to load your icon out of your assembly, set it as an embedded ressource and load it over: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream('<<Path to your ressource>>')`

[Can't load a manifest resource with GetManifestResourceStream()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068750/2630261)
Best way to get the code-base: [Gets the location of the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3324189/2630261)

Comment: When using first part of the answer don't forget to use *absolute path* to the resource - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163495/better-way-to-get-the-base-directory how to get base path.

Comment: Thank you, added it to my answer

Comment: _"move the Icon-File to the Bin/Debug or Bin/Release folder"_ - no, don't do that. Those folders are by convention. You shouldn't add those folders to version control. Just set the "Copy to Output Directory" property properly.